# How do I set up collaboration for working on AOSP?

Tags: android-source, repo

I want to build and work on the Android Open Source Project (AOSP). However, I only have a Windows laptop. To build AOSP on it, I use Linux as a virtual machine (VM) in Windows Hyper-V. I've been able to get older builds like Android 10 to work, but the latest build doesn't seem to work, likely due to performance issues. Nevertheless, theoretically, I can now work with AOSP on my own computer. I can build it, make changes in the codebase, and rebuild it without any problems.

The real challenge arises when I want to collaborate with others. The setup involves two people, each with a Windows computer. Since they are not directly connected and need to independently build the same project, I thought of a solution where the code can be pushed to another computer or a build server.
Here's what I tried: I downloaded the code to my computer, prebuilt the project, deleted the .repo and .git folders in every subfolder, and pushed all the code to Bitbucket. Then, I attempted to build it using TeamCity, but it didn't work. I could build it from scratch, which means letting TeamCity fetch the repo, sync it, select the build, and execute it, but this process took 6 hours and didn't allow me to maintain any code changes.

I'm considering getting another computer, installing Linux on it as a "building machine," and trying to connect both my laptop and my friend's laptop to that machine. However, before I proceed with this, I'd like to ask for guidance on the recommended way to handle this situation.

So, my question is: What is the standard procedure for sharing and building an AOSP codebase when multiple people want to work on it, make changes, and have the project built automatically after each push, which can then be tested in an emulator?